# C++ -- Updating a container inside of a map

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

So I have a `std::shared_ptr<std::map<Vector2,std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Tri>>>>`.

I have a system set up so I can render the Tris that are in the map, so I know what I have so far works.

I am trying to add a new Tri to the vector, if there is a key already in the map for the value I am adding.

Here is the check to see if a value already exists in the map.

```
if((*triangles)[node->getLocation()] != nullptr) {
             UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Value in map" ));
}
```

Soon as I enable this code, the rendering stops, because all the Tris somehow become nullptrs.

Why would this check break the code? And what is the appropriate method adding something to a collection that already exists in a map?

Answer (score 1):

`std::map::operator[]` adds a key to the map (with a default constructed value) if the key is not present in the map.  If you only want to access keys that are present in the map, use `triangles->at(`...key...`)`; this will throw an exception if the key is not present in the map.  If you want to test if a key is present in the map or not, you can use `triangles->count(`...key...`) != 0`